# What is the best way to remove outliers in the task of forecasting demand?

Tags: regression, time-series, outliers, data-preprocessing

I have dataset with over 2500 IDs of products. For each ID I need to remove outliers. I removed them by the condition, that everything what lies over 1.5 * IQR should be deleted, but it seems that when I have sales, for example (1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 10) than 10 will be deleted what is not right, because in fact this sales can be possible. But in this example (1, 5, 1, 2, 1000), 1000 I thing should be removed.
There is no data about promo and I model it with ensemble of ARIMA and linear regression. What is the best way to handle outliers? What is the best decision for treating to observation like outlier.

Comment: Determining outliers can be very subjective sometimes, is your data strictly positive or at least non-negative? Have you tried looking at how many standard deviations away a value is from the mean?

Comment: My data is strictly positive. How many standard deviation away need to be observation for considering it outlier?

Comment: Depends on the field and the data, but values 2, 3, and 4 are good starting places.